# Проверить наличие класса и если есть добавить css

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть меню:

```
<div class="Nav__Megamenu -Fader">
<ul class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--2">
  <li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--0">
   <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2275/">Смеси для пола</a>   </li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--1">
  <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2279/">Затирка</a>
</li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--2">
<a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2276/">Плиточные клеи</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--3"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно проверить, если нету класса Nav__Level--3 то у .Nav__Megamenu сделать фон белым,

```
$(".Nav__Megamenu").map(function(){
    var check_level = $(this).find("Nav__Level--3");
        if(!check_level){
            $(this).css("background", "#fff");
    }
})
```

Вот так не получилось..  p.s делал map потому что Nav__Megamenu -Fader несколько на странице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте правильность использования метода `find`!!! Элемент ищется с указанием `.` или `#`. И переменная всегда будет истинной так как всегда возвращается объект!
Просто так сделайте:

```js
$(".Nav__Megamenu").map(function(){
    var check_level = $(this).find(".Nav__Level--3");
        if(!check_level.length){
            $(this).css("background", "red");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Nav__Megamenu -Fader">
<ul class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--2">
  <li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--0">
   <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2275/">Смеси для пола</a>   </li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--1">
  <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2279/">Затирка</a>
</li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--2">
<a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2276/">Плиточные клеи</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--3"></div>
</div>

<div class="Nav__Megamenu -Fader">
<ul class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--2">
  <li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--0">
   <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2275/">Смеси для пола</a>   </li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--1">
  <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2279/">Затирка</a>
</li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--2">
<a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2276/">Плиточные клеи</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--4"></div>
</div>

<div class="Nav__Megamenu -Fader">
<ul class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--2">
  <li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--0">
   <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2275/">Смеси для пола</a>   </li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--1">
  <a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2279/">Затирка</a>
</li>
<li class="Nav__Item--Sub Nav__Item--Level-2  doubletap" data-next=".Nav__Block--2">
<a class="Nav__Link--Sub Nav__Link--Level-2" href="/category/category_2276/">Плиточные клеи</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="Nav__Sub Nav__Level--4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const item = document.querySelector(".div");

if (item.classList.contains('someClass')) {
    // if true
}
```

Я написал сам принцип, вот для вашего случая

```
var cond = $(".Nav__Megamenu").hasClass("Nav__Level--3");
if (!cond) {
   $(".Nav__Megamenu").css("background", "#fff");
}
```

Comment: $(".Nav__Megamenu").map(function(){
const item = document.querySelector(".Nav__Megamenu");

if (item.classList.contains('Nav__Level--3')) {
    $(this).css("background", "#fff");
}
})
Вот так тоже не срабатывает

Comment: @ilyaaa521,  `$(".Nav__Megamenu").map(function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('Nav__Level--3')) {
    $(this).css("background", "#fff");
  }
});`

Comment: Исправил под ваш случай

Comment: Оно работает но срабатывает сразу для всех Nav__Megamenu, то-есть нужно что то типо $(this).css("background", "#fff");